# Use Multiple Host Threads on a Single GPU

Tags: multithreading, cuda, gpu, ros

Now I'm using ROS to develop a CUDA Project. There are two nodes corresponding to 2 host threads that need to launch 2 different CUDA kernels concurrently.

So I'm wondering:

1. Can a single GPU be called by two host threads concurrently, if I didn't use CUDA Stream?(let's say the GPU resources are enough for launching these two kernels simutaneously.)
2. If not, Why?
3. If I didn't use cuda stream, are these two kernels bound to a single CUDA context or two?
4. If I use CUDA stream, are these two kernels bound to a single CUDA context or two?
5. If they are in two different CUDA context, how does the GPU handle their launching/operations as they are called concurrently?

I am now using a RTX 3090 with CUDA 11.0, and i9-10900k, which has 10 cores.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Can a single GPU be called by two host threads concurrently, if I didn't use CUDA Stream?

Basically no. Threads from the same process share a common context. Contexts only expose concurrency when using streams. You *might* be able to get some degree of concurrency if you build your code to use a [per thread default stream](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/gpu-pro-tip-cuda-7-streams-simplify-concurrency/#:%7E:text=CUDA%207%20introduces%20a%20new,default%20streams%20are%20regular%20streams.), but that is still using streams, just implicitly rather than explicitly.

> 2. If not, Why?

Because that is how NVIDIA designed it.

> 3. If I didn't use cuda stream, are these two kernels bound to a single CUDA context or two?

One. Since CUDA 4 the model is one context per process per device.

> 4. If I use CUDA stream, are these two kernels bound to a single CUDA context or two?

See above

> 5. If they are in two different CUDA context, how does the GPU handle their launching/operations as they are called concurrently?

They are not, so this is moot.